# Automatically Testing Models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I just, manually, discovered a migration error. I added a new field to a model, and forgot to add it into the *model*_params method of the controller. As a result the new field wasn't persisted to the database.

Easy enough to fix once I noticed the problem, but it got me to wondering if there was a way to detect this in testing. I would imagine something like a gem that would parse the schema and generate a set of tests to ensure that all of the fields could be written and that the same data could be read back.

Is this something that can be (or is) done? So far, my searches have led me to lots of interesting reading, but not to a gem like this...

Comment: If you're asking people to locate a third party library to do what you want, please be advised that such requests are off topic for Stack Overflow. Please see the [Stack Overflow help file](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help) for more information. If you're just asking whether what you want is possible, I'm pretty sure it is. Maybe this can be a gem you're willing to contribute to the community.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to write what you would want. Iterate through all the fields in the model, generate params that mirrors those fields, and then run functional tests on your controllers. The problem is that the test is brittle. What if you don't actually want all the fields to be writable through params? What if you reference a model in another controller outside of the standard pattern? How will you handle generating data that would pass different validations? You would either have to be sure that your application would only be written in a certain way or this test would become more and more complex to handle additional edge cases.

I think the solution in testing would be to try to keep things simple; realize that you've made a change to the system and as a result of that change, corresponding tests would need to be updated. In this case, you would update the functional and unit tests affected by that model. If you were strictly adhering to Test Driven Design, you would actually update the tests first to produce a failing test and then implement the change. As a result, hopefully the updated functional test would have failed in this case.

Outside of testing, you may want to look into a linter. In essence, you're asking if you can catch an error where the parameters passed to an object's method doesn't match the signature. This is more catchable when parsing the code completely (i.e. compilation in a static type environment).

EDIT - I skipped a step on the linting, as you would also have to write your code a certain way that a linter would catch it, such as being more explicit of the method and parameters passed to it.

Comment: Very well written answer. I don't really see how a linter would help in this case though as you are basically looking at bunch of ActiveRecord methods that all take `(hash = {}, &block)` although linters like Rubucop are good at catching poor practices and common coding misstakes.

Comment: I wanted to suggest a possible automated way to catch these type of errors "for free," which is what OP wanted, and having a linter analyze code popped into mind first. I think I was suggesting it more as a path to explore in case the OP was unfamiliar. The solution I had in mind was to change coding styles and be more explicit, such as defining your own save methods with explicit parameters. In that case, a linter can catch if you're not passing the correct number of parameters. Admittedly, this would result in boilerplate code and look more Java-esque, so... not the Rails way at all.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider that such a gem may not exist because its not that practical or useful in real life.

Getting the columns off a model is pretty simple from the reflection methods that Active Record gives you. And yeah you could use that theoretically to automagically run a bunch of tests in loop.

But in reality its just not going to cut it. In real life you don't want every column to be assignable. Thats why you are using mass assignment protection in the first place.

And add to that the complexity of the different kinds of constraints and data types your models have. You'll end up with something extremely complex with just adds a bunch of tests with limited value.

If you find yourself omitting a property from mass assignment protection than your should try to cover that part of your controller either with a functional test or an integration test.

```
class ArticlesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def valid_attributes
    { 
      title: 'How to test like a Rockstar',
      content: 'Bla bla bla'
    }
  end

  test "created article should have the correct attributes" do
    post :create, article: valid_attributes
    article = Article.last

    valid_attributes.keys.each do |key|
      assert_equals article[key], valid_attributes[key]
    end
  end
end
```